# Words that end with s BUT exclude words that end with 's

Tags: grep

I need to find a list of 5 letter words beginning with d(upper or lower case) , followed by a lowercase vowel including y and end with s. My command:  grep -i '^d[aeiouy]....s$' file name.   I want to exclude words with 's from my list but I don't know how to do write the command.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  It should be

```
grep -i '^d[aeiouy].[^']s$' file
```

Your number of `.` characters is too many and you want to exclude the penultimate character from being `'`.  Remember, each `.` is a placeholder for one character.  If your words are in running text, you can select them by word delimiters `\<` and `\>` but may have to use `egrep` for that.  If you want to extract all the words in running text meeting your criterion, then you should use:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/\
/g' foobar | grep "^[dD][aeiouy].[^']s$"
```

`sed` allows you to separate all words on a line by itself.  Notice the newline after `\` on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid anchors `^$` you can use `-x` option.
`d` can be upper- or lowcase, but vowel just lowcase
`\B` means `null inside of word` so previous symbol is not any punctuation or space:

```
grep -x '[Dd][aeiouy]..\Bs' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `grep -i "^d[aeiouy]...[^']s$" <file name>`. It excludes the `'` character from the last-but-one position.